# Rank samples from a pool of predictions based on each score

Tags: python, machine-learning, game-theory, shap

I have a pool of samples from `s1` to `s100` that I want to classify between two different categories `A` and `B`

In this problem, I cannot perform predictions individually for each sample but in groups of 10 and every prediction returns the predicted label and the *confidence* for each label. Something like:

```
[s1,s21,s3,s15,s5,s62,s90,s13,s9,s100];A;0.9
[s1,s5,s12,s20,s53,s89,s27,s42,s76,s55];A;0.4
...
```

Every predicted vector is set at random and I can perform as much combinations as needeed. Also, the sample could be repeated more than once in a pool.

What I would like to accomplish is to rank every `sample` importance for each `category` prediction using the *confidence* label

Searching similar problems I end up thinking that computing [shaply values](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/shapley.html) would be a good solution but these are thought to be implementend for features rather than samples.

Any ideas how to implement this?

EDIT:

As suggested I will try to add a minimal example of the issue with 4 samples and 2 samples per group. Something like:

```
Sample_group;Prediction;Confidence
[s1,s2];A;0.7
[s3,s4];A;0.6
[s1,s3];A;0.9
[s2,s4];A;0.5
[s1,s4];A;0.7
[s2,s3];A;0.6
```

Although all pairs give the same prediction, looking at the `confidence` value shows `[s1,s3]` pair has the highest value and `[s2,s4]` has the lowest. Checking the rest of pairs one can infer that `s1` value seems to be the one which gives the highest confidence compared to `s3` when paired with the other two. The result, then, should be something like:

```
Sample;rank
s1;0
s3;1
s2;2
s4;3
```

Comment: Please consider [ask] and [reprex].

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @SergeyBushmanov. I tried to add a minimal example

Answer (score 2):

1. First approach:

You can try to reframe your problem: you actually have a model that takes a 100-feature vector and returns a prediction. Each individual feature is boolean (where feature i is 1 if sample i is one of the 10 included samples and 0 is not; of course this framework can support any mixture of samples and not just groups of 10).

The fact that your prediction has two components can be dealt with by replacing it with a single value, which is the confidence multiplied by either 1 or -1 for prediction A and B, so that your prediction is in the range of [-1 1] (where -1 is predicting A with the highest confidence and 1 is predicting B with the highest confidence, etc.). That's just one suggestion, there can be other ways of reducing your 2D output to 1D but this one seems simplest.

Now that you basically have a simple regression model that takes 100 features and returns a single number, you can compute SHAP values for each feature (which would translate in your case to the "sample importance" - that is, the importance of the sample being included for the prediction). As to how to compute the SHAP values, I think that if you actually implement a class with a .predict method that wraps around your prediction, you could use SHAP's KernelExplainer. Your next problem would be that KernelExplainer gives your shap values for each feature *for a specific prediction* (and runs .predict 100K times to do that so your method better be fast). So you might need to do this many times for different sample groups and average the results.

2. Second approach:

Another option which may take more work to implement but is a more direct solution, is to implement your own version of the Shapley computation.
The original game-theory formulation of Shapley values seems actually more in line with your problem than its adoption for machine learning. That is, if you think of each of your samples as a "contributor" and the final output (reduced to a single number as described above) as the "outcome", then the Shapley formula is exactly intended to estimate the contribution of each contributor being present, across all other permutations of other contributors being present.

In the general case, if you have N contributors, there are 2^N combinations of which are present, but in your case you can say that only combinations where 10 samples exist out of 100 are legal. So you can take the Shapley formula and instead of going over all possible combinations, just go over the legal ones. There are 100 choose 10 which is still a huge number (trillions) so you'd probably need to sample randomly out of it for a reasonable runtime. As far as I understand the idea behind the formula, it will provide you with exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. I guess the second apporach would be the one I would like to implement. Although I guess that `compute_shapley_values` function from here (https://github.com/edden-gerber/radical-shapley-values/blob/master/radical_shapley_values.py) would be a great start, I am not quite sure how to reformat if to fit my needs. Any code hints :-)?

Comment: From taking a quick look to remind myself what I did there, it seems you'd need to modify two main things. One is that instead of running over all 2^M possible coalitions you'll need to define your own loop over possible coalitions, since your'e using only a sub-space of the possible coalitions (my code goes over all possible combinations using a small trick of translating the coalition number into binary, e.g. coalition 5 would be (000...)101 meaning players 1 and 3 participate).

Comment: Second, my function is designed to take a payoff function which takes an input and returns a payoff, and each time passes to that function only the participating features (e.g. partial_X). You can hardcode your own payoff function, and instead of passing to it each time 10 features, always pass to it the 100-element vector with the relevant 10 elements set to 1 and the rest to 0.